# EclipseME eclipseme-build.xml

Tags: java, eclipse

Well firstly I encountered several problems with export Antenna files, ant build : build.xml but that was easy to fix because I found the solution.

Now when I try to do the same with eclipseme-build.xml i get an error:

```
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource antenna.properties. 
It could not be found.

BUILD FAILED
C:\Documents and Settings\...\eclipseme-build.xml:21: Problem: failed to create task or type wtkbuild`
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

The line is this:

```
<target depends="-eclipseme-initialize" name="-eclipseme-build">
  <echo message="Building source files..."/>
  <wtkbuild destdir="${path.build.classes}" encoding="${src.encoding}" source="1.3" sourcepath="" srcdir="${project.root.Client}/res">
     <classpath refid="classpath.Client"/>
  </wtkbuild>
  <wtkbuild destdir="${path.build.classes}" encoding="${src.encoding}" source="1.3" sourcepath="" srcdir="${project.root.Client}/src">
     <classpath refid="classpath.Client"/>
  </wtkbuild>
```

By the way what steps do I need to do that i could export a jar file succesfully that it would run on emulator since now it says "Can`t find Midlet class"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by updatig the ant version.

If you are facing this problem firstly download new Ant version from http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi

Then go on eclipse : 
"Window" - "Prefereces" - "Ant" - "Runtime" ant there you will see a button Ant Home.